# Protecting content of a Docker image

Tags: docker

We are working on an algorithm which we want to keep confidential, but we need to deploy it on some Linux devices administered by 3rd parties. We need a solution to distribute it as a "black box". Is delivering the algorithm in a Docker image a reliable way to protect it?

Answer (score 1):

No. Docker images are just fancy disk images. They offer no protection whatsoever.